# How to write API with multiple parameter in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, get

I'm a bit new to Node.js and writing some GET REST APIs in Express.js. For one of my API, I need to pass 2 parameters to get the data from the database. I have achieved it using a single parameter but not more than 2. anyone help me, please?

Here my function

```
getByNPPTahunBulan(req,res){
        console.log(req.param.tahun_bulan)
        Iuran_Dapen.findAll({
            where: {
                tahun_bulan: req.params.tahun_bulan,
                npp: req.param.npp
            }
        }).then((data) => {
            return res.send(data);
            }).catch((err) => {
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while retrieving data.',
                });
            })
    },
```

and the url `router.get('/iuranterakhir/:tahun_bulan/:npp', iuranDapen.getByNPPTahunBulan);`

Comment: do you want to use multi-parameter with database or with the request

Comment: `req.param.npp` needs to be `req.params.npp`, this was simply caused by a typo. you correctly used `params` in the `tahun_bulan`, but forgot the "s" in the `npp`. You also forgot the "s" in your `console.log()` function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

req.params contains a parameter object with its respective value with the following url `/:id/:name`
ej.

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'foo'
}
```

and you can do something like this:

```
const params = req.params;
```

and access as follows

```
params.id or params.name
```

the keys of the objects depends on the name of the parameters that you have given in the definition of your endpoint